# Transfomation of a strictly decreasing random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

[image]

I get that $Y\leq y \iff X \geq g^{-1}(y)$, where $Y=g(X)$ and $g^{-1}(y)$ is the preimage of $y$ but why does this mean that : $Pr(Y \leq y)=Pr(X \geq g^{-1}(y))$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the two sets $\{Y\leq y\}$ and $\{X\geq g^{-1}(y)\}$ are equal, their probabilities $P(Y\leq y)$ and $P(X\geq g^{-1}(y))$ are, of course, also equal.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by equal. If I take an arbitrary element from one of the sets it is not necessarily in the other.

Comment: Yes, since $g$ is assumed decreasing, an element is in $\{Y\leq y\}$ if and only if it is in $\{X\geq g^{-1}(y)\}$. Mathematically, $$\omega\in \{Y\leq y\}\iff Y(\omega)=g(X(\omega))\leq y\iff X(\omega)\geq g^{-1}(y)\iff \omega\in \{X\geq g^{-1}(y)\}.$$